# Having segmentation fault printf %s in C bison

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bison

I tried to give an output if tag names of begin and end tags did not match ,but  I am having segmentation fault when I want to print it.

in .y

```
list_attr:      /* empty rule */
                | attribute list_attr
                ;
tag_name:       tCOURSE {$$=makeTag($1,COURSE);}
                | tCLASS {$$=makeTag($1,CLASS);}
                | tMEETING{$$=makeTag($1,MEETING);}
                | tCONSTRAINT{$$=makeTag($1,CONSTRAINT);}
                | tITEM{$$=makeTag($1,ITEM);}
                ;
tag_begin:      tOPEN tag_name list_attr tCLOSE {$$=makeTagBegin($1,$2);}
                ;
    tag_end:        tLEND tag_name tCLOSE    {$$=makeTagEnd($1,$2);}

    tag_self:       tOPEN tag_name list_attr tSELF {$$=makeTagSelf($1,$2,$4);}
                    ;
    element:        tag_begin list_element tag_end  {if( $1->exprNodePtr->tags.tName != $3->exprNodePtr->tags.tName)  
  printf("Tag Mismatch between %s and %s \n",$1->exprNodePtr->tags.tName, $3->exprNodePtr->tags.tName ); }
                    | tag_self 
                    ;
...... continue


 TreeNode* makeTag(char * v, TagName ta)
 {
   TreeNode * result2 = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
   result2->thisNodeType=TAG;
   result2->exprNodePtr=(ExprNode*)malloc(sizeof(ExprNode));
   result2->exprNodePtr->tags.value=v;
   result2->exprNodePtr->tags.tName=ta;
   return(result2);
 }
TreeNode* makeTagBegin(char * v, TreeNode * t)
{
  TreeNode* result3 = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
  result3->thisNodeType=TAG;
  result3->exprNodePtr=(ExprNode*)malloc(sizeof(ExprNode));
  result3->exprNodePtr->tags.value=strdup(v);
  result3->exprNodePtr->tags.tName= t->exprNodePtr->tags.tName;
  return(result3);
}
TreeNode* makeTagEnd(char * v, TreeNode *tr)
{
  TreeNode* result4 = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
  result4->thisNodeType=TAG;
  result4->exprNodePtr=(ExprNode*)malloc(sizeof(ExprNode));
  result4->exprNodePtr->tags.value=strdup(v);
  result4->exprNodePtr->tags.tName=tr->exprNodePtr->tags.tName;
  return(result4);

}
TreeNode* makeTagSelf(char*v, TreeNode*tre,char*v4)
{
  TreeNode* result5 = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
  result5->thisNodeType=TAG;
  result5->exprNodePtr=(ExprNode*)malloc(sizeof(ExprNode));
  result5->exprNodePtr->tags.value=strdup(v4);
  result5->exprNodePtr->tags.tName=tre->exprNodePtr->tags.tName;
  return(result5);

}
```

and my header file i have

```
typedef enum {ATTR,TAG} NodeType;
typedef enum {STRING,NUMBER,TIME,DAY} AttrType;
typedef enum {COURSE,CLASS,MEETING,CONSTRAINT,ITEM} TagName;
typedef enum{LEND,CLOSE,OPEN,SELF} SymbolType;

//For String

typedef struct AttrNode
{
     char * value; 
     AttrType type; 
}AttrNode;

typedef struct TagNode
{
    char * value;
    TagName tName;
    SymbolType stype;
}TagNode;

typedef union {
AttrNode attr;
TagNode tags;
} ExprNode;

 typedef struct TreeNode
 {
  NodeType thisNodeType; 
  AttrNode *attrNodePtr; 
  TagNode *tagNodePtr;
  ExprNode* exprNodePtr;

 }TreeNode;


TreeNode * makeATTR(char * v, AttrType t);
TreeNode *makeTag(char * v, TagName ta);
TreeNode* makeTagBegin(char * v, TreeNode* t);
TreeNode* makeTagEnd(char * v, TreeNode *tr);
TreeNode* makeTagSelf(char*v, TreeNode*tre,char*v4);
```

I am having segmentation fault. The number of the mismatch of the tags are correct ,but I want to print like that:

> Tag mismatch between name-in-begin-tag and name-in-end-tag

and also I dont understand where is my problem.

Outputs:

> In file included from .flx:6: .h:1:16: warning: extra tokens at end of ifndef directive
>
> .h:2:16: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
>
> In file included from .y:5: .h:1:16: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
>
> .h:2:16: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name In function ‘yyparse’:
>
> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘makeATTR’ from incompatible pointer type
>
> Below from my printf
>
> Type Mismatch between code= and 192
>
> Type Mismatch between type= and 14:00
>   Segmentation fault**

Comment: .tName is not a string but an enum. You could start by printing it with a `%d` format.

Comment: @wildplasser when i changed it to %d i got Tag mismatch between 1 and 0 Tag mismatch between 0 and 1 outputs. I want the tag names printed.

Comment: It's an enum, they don't **have** names.